# Appboy SDK. How to hide visit indicator for News Feed cards?

Tags: ios, appboy, braze

I don't want show visit indicator in news feed cards. Anybody know how to hide that indicators? [image]

It means a triangle with a dot.

Comment: providing some screenshots (i.e. current & expected) will help us have a better idea on how to give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

@property (nonatomic) BOOL disableUnreadIndicator;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disableUnreadIndicator`

`newsFeed.newsFeed.disableUnreadIndicator = !self.unreadIndicatorSwitch.on;`

https://github.com/Appboy/appboy-ios-sdk/blob/b99d346646bb1d386ac75db5f4cc8cfeb382fb4a/Samples/NewsFeed/BrazeNewsFeedSample/BrazeNewsFeedSample/ViewController.m#L8